# Base class reference in Derived class ctor

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

Is this a good practice in C++ 11 (or in OOP generally)?

```
class Base
{
    public:
        Base(Base && other) = default;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived(Base && base, int derivedParam)
        : Base(std::move(base)), derivedParam_m(derivedParam)
        {
        }
};
```

The only draw-back i can think of is that it allows initializing derived class with some other derived class what can make a code looks pretty weird if misused.

```
class Shape;
class Circle : public Shape;
class Triangle : public Shape;

...
...
new Triangle{new Circle{p, r}, x, y, z}
```

Comment: Why not just pass a `Base *` ?   Makes more sense as it will need to be deleted later.

Comment: Having to use two `new`s when constructing an object doesn't seem like an advantage at all.

Comment: The `Triangle` and `Circle` snip serves as an example what such construction allows. Base object can be moved from temp object or local variable.